# Haskell GHC WebAssembly Backend - Memory Access Out of Bounds Error

Tags: haskell, webassembly, ghc

I've been working on a browser-based Snake game using Haskell's GHC WebAssembly backend. The game runs initially but after a while, it crashes with the following error in the console:

```
experiment.wasm:0x980d Uncaught (in promise) RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds
at dlmalloc (experiment.wasm:0x980d)
at malloc (experiment.wasm:0x9696)
at Main_zdfstableZZC1ZZCmainZZCMainZZCmallocPtr1_entry (experiment.wasm:0xeb924)
at StgRun (experiment.wasm:0xdd9e)
at scheduleWaitThread (experiment.wasm:0xcfe47)
at rts_inCall (experiment.wasm:0x45322)
at mallocPtr (experiment.wasm:0xee14b)
at Ut
```

I've shared my Haskell code (Main.hs) and JavaScript code (Main.js) below:

Main.hs

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE JavaScriptFFI #-}
{-# LANGUAGE CApiFFI #-} 
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}


import qualified Data.ByteString.UTF8 as BSU 
import Data.ByteString.Unsafe (unsafePackMallocCStringLen, unsafeUseAsCStringLen)
import Foreign (Ptr, copyBytes, mallocBytes, poke, malloc, free)
import Foreign.C (CChar)
import Data.IORef
import System.IO.Unsafe
import System.Random.Mersenne (randomIO)
import Prelude hiding (Left, Right)

data Direction = Up | Down | Left | Right deriving (Show, Eq)

type Position = (Int, Int)

data GameState = GameState
    { snake :: [Position]
    , direction :: Direction
    , food :: Position
    } deriving (Show)

width :: Int
width = 20

height :: Int
height = 20

initialGameStateIO :: IO GameState
initialGameStateIO = do 
    let initialSnake = [(width `div` 2, height `div` 2)]
    GameState initialSnake Right <$> randomPosition

randomPosition :: IO Position
randomPosition = do
    x <- randomIO --(0, width - 1)
    y <- randomIO --(0, height - 1)
    let x' = x `mod` width
    let y' = y `mod` height
    pure (x', y')


initialGameState :: IORef GameState
initialGameState = unsafePerformIO $ newIORef =<< initialGameStateIO
{-# NOINLINE initialGameState #-}


main :: IO ()
main = mempty

foreign export capi mallocPtr :: IO (Ptr (Ptr a))

mallocPtr :: IO (Ptr (Ptr a))
mallocPtr = malloc


foreign export capi freePtr :: Ptr a -> IO ()

freePtr :: Ptr a -> IO ()
freePtr = free


foreign export capi updateGameState :: Ptr CChar -> Int -> Ptr (Ptr CChar) -> IO Int

updateGameState :: Ptr CChar -> Int -> Ptr (Ptr CChar) -> IO Int
updateGameState inputPtr inputLen outputPtrPtr = do

    input <- unsafePackMallocCStringLen (inputPtr, inputLen)
    gameState <- readIORef initialGameState
    randomPosition' <- randomPosition

    let direction' = case input of
        "ArrowUp" -> Up
        "ArrowDown" -> Down
        "ArrowLeft" -> Left
        "ArrowRight" -> Right
        _ -> direction gameState
    let newSnakeHead = case direction' of
        Up -> (x, y - 1)
        Down -> (x, y + 1)
        Left -> (x - 1, y)
        Right -> (x + 1, y)
        where
            (x, y) = head $ snake gameState

    let (newFood, gotFood) = if newSnakeHead == food gameState
        then (randomPosition', True)
        else (food gameState, False)


    let newSnake = if gotFood
        then newSnakeHead : snake gameState
        else take (length $ snake gameState) $ newSnakeHead : snake gameState
    

    let newGameState = GameState newSnake direction' newFood

    let output = gameStateToString newGameState


    writeIORef initialGameState newGameState

    unsafeUseAsCStringLen (BSU.fromString output) $ \(buf, len) -> do
    outputPtr <- mallocBytes len
    poke outputPtrPtr outputPtr
    copyBytes outputPtr buf len
    pure len

gameStateToString :: GameState -> String
gameStateToString gameState = unlines rows
    where
    rows = [[charAt (x, y) | x <- [0..width - 1]] | y <- [0..height - 1]]
    charAt pos
        | pos `elem` snake gameState = '*'
        | pos == food gameState = '@'
        | otherwise = '.'
```

main.js

```js
import { WASI } from "@bjorn3/browser_wasi_shim/src";

const wasi = new WASI([], [], []);

const wasiImportObj = { wasi_snapshot_preview1: wasi.wasiImport };
const wasm = await WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch("experiment.wasm"), wasiImportObj);
wasi.inst = wasm.instance;
const exports = wasm.instance.exports;
const memory = exports.memory;
const encoder = new TextEncoder();
const decoder = new TextDecoder();


exports._initialize();
exports.hs_init(0, 0);

const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
console.log(canvas);

const width = 20;
const height = 20;

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const cellSize = 20;

canvas.width = width * cellSize;
canvas.height = height * cellSize;

async function update() {

    if (!window.direction) {
        window.direction = 's';
    }

    const inputLen = Buffer.byteLength(window.direction);
    const inputPtr = exports.malloc(inputLen);
    const inputArr = new Uint8Array(memory.buffer, inputPtr, inputLen);
    encoder.encodeInto(window.direction, inputArr);
    const outputPtrPtr = exports.mallocPtr();
    const outputLen = exports.updateGameState(inputPtr, inputLen, outputPtrPtr);
    const outputPtrArr = new Uint32Array(memory.buffer, outputPtrPtr, 1);
    const outputPtr = outputPtrArr[0];
    const outputArr = new Uint8Array(memory.buffer, outputPtr, outputLen);
    const output = decoder.decode(outputArr);

    exports.freePtr(inputPtr);
    exports.freePtr(outputPtr);
    exports.freePtr(outputPtrPtr);

    console.log(exports) 

    draw(output);
    // delay
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 150));

    if (window.isRunning) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }
}

    function draw(gameStateStr) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    const rows = gameStateStr.trim().split('\n');
    console.log(rows)

    for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        const c = rows[y][x];
        if (c === '*') {
            ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
            ctx.fillRect(x * cellSize, y * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
        } else if (c === '@') {
            ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
            ctx.fillRect(x * cellSize, y * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
        }

        }
    }
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
    window.direction = event.key;
    console.log(event.key);
});

window.start = () => {
    window.isRunning = true;
    console.log('start');
    console.log(window);
    update();
};

window.stop = () => {
    window.isRunning = false;
};

function init() {
    window.start();
}

init();
```

I am suspecting the issue might be related to memory management or some unsafe operations, but I'm not exactly sure where the problem lies. I've tried to debug the issue, but I'm struggling to find the root cause.

Could anyone help me identify what's causing the memory access out of bounds error and suggest how to fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Repo here: https://github.com/charles37/haskell-wasm-snake